# Outlook 'One or more items in the folder you synchronized do not match' error in C# add in

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin

I have an add-in that goes into the default calendar folder of Outlook, and goes through the calendar appointments to get some data out of them (like start & finish dates).

There is one machine, with Windows 7, Outlook 2010 (version 14.0.0.4760 - using Exchange 2010), which throws the following error, when running the add-in:

> One or more items in the folder you synchronized do not match. To resolve the conflicts, open the items, and then try this operation again.

Here's the code snippet, where I get the calendar appointments. Afterwards i just go through the **filteredItems** with a simple foreach cycle.

```
Outlook.Application OutlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
ns = OutlookApp.Session;
calendarFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
calendarFolderItems = calendarFolder.Items;
String DateFilter = "[Start] >= '" + FilterStart.ToString("g") + "' AND [End] <= '" + FilterEnd.ToString("g") + "'";
filteredItems = calendarFolderItems.Restrict(DateFilter);
calAppointmentname = new string[filteredItems .Count + 1];
```

It also happens on this machine, that while trying to send out an email, the Outlook client itself throws this error in a dialog box, so could it be an internal thing?

I also found out, that a faulty calendar appointment can cause this issue.
How can I get the faulty calendar object, so I could return its name and show a dialog box for the end-user? Do I need to use the Conflict object, and if yes, what is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

Try following the steps found at [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190128213736/http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/support/support_gsyncit_olsyncfail.shtml):

> How to correct the error "one or more items in folder you
> synchronized do not match" ...
>
> 1. Open the folder list view in Outlook by clicking on "View/Folder List".
> 2. Highlight one of the folders (Calendar, Contacts, Tasks, or Notes) where you suspect the problem exists, and change its view to ‘By
>    Category'. To do this click on "View/Current View/By Category".
> 3. Sort the records ‘By icon’. To do this, click the folded page icon in the title bar above the category heading.)
> 4. Click on the "+" sign next to the "Category" heading and scroll down until you find one or more items with a crossed swords icon.
>    Click here to see a picture of a "crossed sword" icon.
> 5. Double-click on the item with crossed-swords and from the "Conflict Resolution" window select to keep the item with the most
>    recent date.
> 6. Synchronize.

Comment: What is the "folder list view"? I don't see a "View/Folder List" option/button anywhere.